# How should students (who go to secular schools) practice Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, schools

How should students who go to secular schools behave and practise Hinduism according to the Dharma Shastras?

Comment: Read Bhagavad Geeta, Ramayan, Puranas, Upanishads and Tantric texts. Once you identified your taste you can consult guru and start your sadhna.

Comment: @GopalSharma but don't you need a guru to read and understand such texts you mentioned like the Upanishads etc?

Comment: By reading these you will not understand first, but your will get a taste and continue your journey with the help of guru.

Comment: @GopalSharma but how do you know you're getting the right taste? Why not just go to the guru, as you will get both the understanding and the taste from him and you will know that you have the proper taste and understanding (ofc under a right guru).

Comment: You can directly go to guru, but how do you find the right guru,that's a quesiton. There are some paragraph mentioned in Yoga Vashistha, which says, a person interested in spritual things, collects and reads spritual books, visit spritiual places. In intial level he is called jigyasu(seeker) and if he continues the seeking he will reach the higher stages in this birth or later. You call follow any path, either seek guru first and start practicing the sadhna or read books, get some understanding and then guru and sadhna.

Comment: @GopalSharma I don't quite understand what you are saying.

Comment: If you directly go to a guru, most probabaly you will find a crook, because good guru's are not visible in public life. They are living very secret life, it's very hard to find them. Also even if you found a guru, he may not be teaching something you are interested in. So follow accordingly. i hope that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146756/discussion-between-rajam-and-gopal-sharma).

Comment: I notice that you've been creating a _lot_ of tags for your questions. I think it would be nice if you could do that less because many of these tags won't have much future use.  Tags should describe overarching concepts or ideas that recur. You can continue to create them, of course, but maybe just not so many. Thanks :)

Comment: @CDR sorry for the overuse of tags. I will try to lower the amount of tags I use from now on :)

Comment: @Rajam - thanks. Nothing to be sorry for, btw.